# Bind a service to several times the same service provider with NInject

Tags: c#, ninject

I'd like to use multiple binding for multiple injection with NInject, just as [the official documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) states, but using several times the same binding.

```
public class Samurai 
{
    readonly IWeapon[] allWeapons;
    public Samurai(IWeapon[] allWeapons) 
    {
        this.allWeapons = allWeapons;
    }

    public void Attack(string target) 
    {
        foreach (IWeapon weapon in this.allWeapons)
            Console.WriteLine(weapon.Hit(target));
    }
}
```

Then, instead of giving the `Samurai` a `Sword` and a `Dagger` as the official example, I want him to have a lot of `Shuriken`. Of course I can loop over the binding, but is there a better way to do that? Maybe define an extension method?

```
class TestModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            Bind<IWeapon>().To<Shuriken>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a DI container is not a good fit to fulfill this requirement. If anything i would somewhere configure what type and how many `IWeapon` you want to instanciate and bind a provider for `ICollection<IWeapon>` which then can create these according to configuration.